# curve 25519 scalar multiplication library

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, curve-25519

I am porting some backend/sdk to nodejs/typescript and I came along a blocker,
the source uses `libsodium` function `crypto_scalarmult_curve25519()` which has an equivalent in Go as well thru `crypto/curve25519` (`ScalarMult`).

It's been hour since I was looking a similar version in nodejs/typescript, I even tried the javascript version of `libsodium`; which pointed me to `libsodium-wrapper`, which unfortunately the function I am looking for (`crypto_scalarmult_curve25519`) is missing and not supported. `crypto` library nor the `node-forge` does not have curve scalar multiplication as well.

Is there any alternative in javascript/typescript?

Comment: "i even tried the javascript version of libsodium" which one? Because https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium is an emscripten port, which means if it's in the C++ library, it's in the resulting JS library (because that's what emscripten does.)

Comment: this one https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium.js, if you open the libsodium.js file itself and search for the function crypto_scalarmult_curve25519 its not there.
maybe its been wrap or something?

Comment: Don't look for TypeScript, look for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

found a very lightweight curve25519 library for typescript.
https://github.com/harveyconnor/curve25519-js/

by default the scalar multiplication functions is not exposed to outside user of the library, so i need to export it from the source to be used.

answering my question for others to use.